# convergence on $L^p$ space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> Let $ \displaystyle{ f \in L^p (\mathbb R^n), 1\leq p <\infty }$ and
>   let $ \upsilon \in \mathbb R^n$. For $h>0$ define $\displaystyle{
>  f_h(x) = \frac{1}{h} \int_0^h f(x+s \upsilon) ds }$.
>
> Prove that: $\displaystyle{ f_h \to f}$, in $L^p (\mathbb R^n)$ as $h
>  \to 0^+ .$

I tried to do it by approximating $f$ by functions of compact support, but I didn't succeed to end it. I also tried to use to estimate using the operator $\tau_\alpha f (x):= f(x+ \alpha \upsilon)$ and then using Jensen's inequality and Fubini's theorem, I got to that:

$\displaystyle{ \| f_h -f\|_{L^p}^p \leq \int_0^1 \|\tau_{sh} - f\|_{L^p}^p ds }$

I think that it isn't that hard, but I am missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, we have to prove that 
$$\int_0^1\lVert\tau_{shv}(f)-f\rVert_{\mathbb L^p}^p\mathrm ds\to 0\mbox{ as }h\to 0.$$
Let $g$ be a continuous function with compact support such that $\lVert f-g\rVert_{\mathbb L^p}^p\lt \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is a positive arbitrary but fixed number. We have 
\begin{align}\lVert\tau_{shv}(f)-f\rVert_{\mathbb L^p}^p&\leqslant 2^p(\lVert\tau_{shv}(f)-\tau_{shv}(g)\rVert_{\mathbb L^p}^p+\lVert\tau_{shv}(g)-g\rVert_{\mathbb L^p}^p+\lVert g-f\rVert_{\mathbb L^p}^p)\\
&\leqslant 2^p(2\varepsilon+\lVert\tau_{shv}(g)-g\rVert_{\mathbb L^p}^p).
\end{align}
Using the fact that $g$ has a compact support and is uniformly continuous, we have 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^1\lVert\tau_{shv}(g)-g\rVert_{\mathbb L^p}^p\mathrm ds=0.$$

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer! Now I have two questions regarding your solution. 1) I suppose you use the fact that $\tau_{sh \upsilon}$ is an isometry, but  why $|\tau_\alpha f -\tau_\alpha g|=|f(x+\alpha)-g(x+\alpha)| = |f-g|$ ? 2) h is a positive real number, I can't understand the point your are saying: " fact that h has a compact support and is uniformly continuous".

Comment: I've edited, $h$ should be $g$. I used a substitution in order to have $\lVert\tau_{shv}(f)-\tau_{shv}(g)\rVert_{\mathbb L^p}=\lVert f- g\rVert_{\mathbb L^p}$.

Comment: One last question: could you please explain me how you conclude the last equality, and how exactly do you you use the fact that $g$ has compact support and is uniformly continuous? Couls we use Lebesgue's dominated Convergence Theorem somehow?

Comment: Yes, dominated convergence theorem applies because $\tau_{shv}(g)$ has it support contained in $\operatorname{supp}(h)+\lVert v\rVert B(0,1)$ when $h\lt 1$. Alternatively, we can integrate over the latter set, fix $\varepsilon$ and take $\delta$ for which $|g(x)-g(y)|\lt \varepsilon$ if $|x-y|\lt \delta$, hence if $|hv|\lt \delta$, $|\tau_{shv}(g)-g|\leqslant \varepsilon\lambda_n(\operatorname{supp}(h)+\lVert v\rVert B(0,1))$.

Comment: I suppose that $\lambda_n$ denotes the $n-$dimensional Lebesgue measure. I think that you miswrite $h$ instead of $g$. Anyway, every step is clear now. Thank you very much for your answer and your time!

Comment: Yes, it should be $g$ again. You are welcome.